# Activate other Application - OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am writing an application which opens another application up. The other application is an agent so the user could not see anything in the dock.

If the user clicks on the dock symbol of the first app, I'd like to check if there is any other agent opened up but not active. If it's so i want to activate the second app instead of opening the first app. If there's no other agent opened I want to open the main app in a normal way.

Does anybody know if this is possible , or does anybody actually have a solution?

I'd appreciate every help, cheers.

Comment: Is this a *Launch Agent*?  Please show the configuration `.plist` contents.

Comment: The second app has an application is an agent - YES in it's plist, the other one is just a normal application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is, how to activate another app? `NSRunningApplication` has `-activateWithOptions:` for that purpose. Something like this:

```
NSRunningApplication *otherApp = [NSRunnungApplication runningApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:…];
[otherApp activateWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: could you explain how to use the bundleIdentifier? I am not able to get this working!

Comment: You should know your agents bundle identifier?

Comment: Yes, there was another problem but now it works perfectly.

Comment: do you also know how to activate an application if the application is minimised? activateWithOptions doesn't work here.

Comment: Hoooo, never tried that. Die you try `-unhide` (`NSRunningApplication`)? Maybe there is a property for the agent to be unhidden with every activation. I remember something like that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes I tried but it didn't work, although -> thank you for your help